# Terraform not deploying into multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I'm having an issue with terraform/terragrunt deploying into multiple accounts. I want to manage DNS and KMS in my "master" account and deploy everything else into my dev/uat/prod environments.

I've configured multiple AWS accounts using the providers. One is auto-created through terragrunt and the other one is creating within my main.tf file.

I've tried many different ways to get this to work. Aliasing both providers, setting just one provider with an alias and removing terragrunt completely from the equation. In every case, the terraform is being applied to my "master" account for all resources..

Below is an example of my code:

```
  backend = "s3"
#   generate = {
#       path = "backend.tf"
#       if_exists = "overwrite"
#   }
  config = {
    bucket                  = "arm-terraform-state"
    key                     = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region                  = "us-west-2"
    dynamodb_table          = "arm-terraform-state-lock"
  }
  generate = {
    path = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
}
generate "provider" {
  path = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents = <<EOF
provider "aws" {
  alias                   = "main"
  region                  = "${local.aws_region}"
  profile                 = "${local.account}"
}
EOF
}
locals {
    region_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("region.hcl"))
    account_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("account.hcl"))
    aws_region   = local.region_vars.locals.aws_region
    account = local.account_vars.locals.aws_profile
}
```

Above is my Terragrunt code.
This is my module:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "logging_role_policy" {
  provider = aws.main
  name = format("aws-sftp-logging-policy-%s-%s",var.product_name,var.env)

  role= aws_iam_role.logging_role.id

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sftp_logging.json
}
############
# Route 53 #
############
resource "aws_route53_record" "sftp_record" {
  provider = aws.master
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.facteus.zone_id
  name = format("%s-%s",var.product_name,var.env)
  type = "CNAME"
  ttl = "30"
  records = [aws_transfer_server.aws_transfer_service.endpoint]
}
```

Comment: The local.account gets populated from within my terraform heirarchy.

Comment: So each environment has it's own `account.hcl` that defines a different profile?

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that at the bottom

Comment: Also, the typical way to do this kind of thing is using `role_arn` for the AWS provider and configuring roles which can be assumed on different accounts

Comment: @jordanm, Yes each account.hcl declares the environment to provision into. I am using a role here: 
```
############
# Provider #
############
provider "aws" {
  alias = "master"
  region = "us-west-2"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = <ARN>
  }
}
```
Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: No, that looks right, but that's not what you have in your question. You are using `profile` instead of `role_arn` (although both can be used together). You can pass the role in as a normal input variable

Comment: There should be no reason to have to generate the provider config to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by creating a directory structure that mirrors your desired account structure. Based on your question, it sounds like you might want something like this:

```
├── dev
│   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── us-east-1
├── master
│   ├── _global
│   │   └── dns
│   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── us-east-1
│       └── kms
├── prod
│   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── us-east-1
└── uat
    ├── terragrunt.hcl
    └── us-east-1
```

The `master` account here has two directories that the others do not have:

1. `_global/dns` - since Route 53 in AWS is a global entity (not regional), you don't want to nest it under `us-east-1`. It only lives in the `master` account since you stated that you want to control DNS from master. (I'd also recommend naming it `route53` rather than `dns`, but I digress.)
2. `us-east-1/kms` - This contains the KMS configuration, also only for `master`.

Now, in `master/terragrunt.hcl`, set up your `remote_state` configuration:

```
remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    encrypt        = true
    bucket         = "master-terraform-state" # Just for example - must be a globally unique
    key            = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-locks"
  }
}
```

Optionally, you can also include an [`iam_role` attribute](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#iam_role):

```
iam_role = "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_NAME"
```

Note that this is optional because you can also simply execute Terragrunt with the credentials for the master account, or you can use the `--terragrunt-iam-role` CLI option, or you can set the `TERRAGRUNT_IAM_ROLE` env var. In all cases, you'll be executing terragrunt with the role that has permissions for the master account.

Now, for dev/uat/prod accounts, you can have a similar `remote_state` configuration, substituting a different bucket name for each of them. You can then use the IAM role appropriate to each of these accounts, either by defining it as `iam_role` in the `terragrunt.hcl` within each account, or by the other methods I mentioned.

TL;DR You don't need to generate the provider for this, and you don't need to name the profile in the provider configuration. You simply execute terragrunt with the correct IAM role for each account. Terragrunt will assume the role before invoking Terraform. Put the provider configuration in your Terraform module, leaving the profile off.

Comment: Interesting, so if I want to leverage the resources the are created in DNS and in KMS. I'll need to make sure to run an apply on those before I run the apply on the "sftp" environments?

Comment: Also if I do this, I need to account for any Route53 additions that I may want in my module creation, correct?

Comment: >  I'll need to make sure to run an apply on those before I run the apply on the "sftp" environments?
I do not know what the "sftp" environments are, but if you want to reference resources in the master accounts in the child accounts, you would need to make sure the master account is up to date first.

Comment: >  I need to account for any Route53 additions that I may want in my module creation, correct?

I don't quite understand your question here. Since you want to manage route53 in your master account, any resources records/hosted zone changes/etc need to be done in the master account since that's where you have the route53 module.

Comment: Note that I wouldn't recommend managing DNS in the master account. I'd create a hosted zone related to each environment in its own account. This ≠

Comment: I'm creating Route53 records, so I would want to make sure that when I build out my module it accounts for the different types of records, even though I'm only creating a CNAME at this point. The issue that I have with hosting the zones in each account is the fact that our .com zone is going to be used for many products across our environments.

Comment: This is getting off topic now, but you could always delegate subdomains for the non-production accounts and keep the root domain in the prod account. Or even use different domains for the non prod accounts.

Comment: Okay I apologize. Thank you for your help